# Eclipse CDT - hover window recursion / nested hover windows

Tags: eclipse, hover, eclipse-cdt

I work at huge embedded-C projects with nested typedefs and functions that I regularly lose track of.
 
I usually do quick checkups with the hover-window, but that doesn't work well for nested typedefs. So backtracking types then requires allot of jumping through the code, which is confusing and takes allot of time.
There it would come in handy, to be able to use the same hover-functionality inside hover-windows.

I edited a screenshot to show the desired functionality:

[image: "Screenshot" of what I want Eclipse to do]

So is there any way to get recursion into hover-windows?
Or is there any workaround / plugin to achieve easy backtracking of nested typedefs / nested functions?

Thanks guys,
Janis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature simply does not exist in eclipse. You might want to add it as something for Kepler, although I don't think you'd get what you want even then. You might have to wait a lot longer for that. There are no plug-ins that I am aware of, that provides this kind of functionality either. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, well appreciated. Sad to hear though that there is no solution for this, in my opinion this would have been a great feature for big / unfamiliar projects...